# How to configure CentOS firewalld to allow quagga ospf messages

Tags: centos7, ospf, quagga

I have a 4 node spine leaf topology with tow host connected. One host each connected to the leaves. Each host is also hosting quagga and capable of operating as a router.

On the (CentOS 7) host OSPF will not converge until I disable firewalld. The status below is present on the leaf.

```
Neighbor ID     Pri State           Dead Time Address         Interface            RXmtL RqstL DBsmL
5.5.5.5           1 Init/DROther      37.933s 10.6.1.2        swp3:10.6.1.1            0     0     0
```

The host remains in the init state and only converges after disabling firewalld. I don't want to stop firewalld; How can I configure firewalld to allow ospf messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSPF is IP protocol 89, so you need to allow this protocol:

```
firewall-cmd --add-protocol=ospf [--permanent] [--zone=whatever]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the following issue with the previous answer:

```
firewall-cmd --add-protocol=ospf
Error: INVALID_PROTOCOL: ospf
```

So after pulling some hairs, I found this solution:

```
firewall-cmd --add-protocol=89
```

Which does work